# Firebase Analytics does not log any event when building from build server

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

We did integrate Firebase Analytics by using setup instructions documented here (using cocoapods):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Everything works as espected when starting/building the app from xcode (as debug). Every event gets logged.

Source to init:

```
DDLogDebug(@"FB: Init");
FIRApp *defaultApp = [FIRApp defaultApp];
if (!defaultApp) {
    DDLogDebug(@"FB: No default app");
    NSString *configPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
    if (configPath) {
        DDLogDebug(@"FB: Hurraaaa, The firebase GoogleService-Info.plist file is in bundle, configPath: %@", configPath);
        NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:configPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        DDLogDebug(@"FB: File is: %@", file);

        FIROptions *options = [FIROptions defaultOptions];
        DDLogDebug(@"APIKey          = %@", options.APIKey);
        DDLogDebug(@"trackingID      = %@", options.trackingID);
        DDLogDebug(@"googleAppID     = %@", options.googleAppID);
        DDLogDebug(@"clientID        = %@", options.clientID);
        DDLogDebug(@"GCMSenderID     = %@", options.GCMSenderID);
        DDLogDebug(@"androidClientID = %@", options.androidClientID);
        DDLogDebug(@"databaseURL     = %@", options.databaseURL);
        DDLogDebug(@"storageBucket   = %@", options.storageBucket);
        DDLogDebug(@"bundleID        = %@", options.bundleID);
        DDLogDebug(@"projectID       = %@", options.projectID);

        [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
        DDLogDebug(@"FB: DID CONFIGURE");
    } else {
        DDLogDebug(@"FB: Warning: The firebase config file is missing.");
        DDLogWarn(@"Warning: The firebase config file is missing.");
    }
} else {
    DDLogDebug(@"FB: Have a default app");
}
```

Source to log:

```
NSDictionary *params = [self paramsForTrackingEvent:trackingEvent
                           usingTrackingEventConfig:trackingEventConfig];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:[[weakSelf conformsString:compiledActionTemplate] pk_truncateByIndex:kFirebaseAnalyticsKeyMaxCount]
                        parameters:params.allKeys.count > 0 ? params : nil];
});
DDLogDebug(@"*** TRACK [FIREBASE_ANALYTICS,ACTION]: %@", compiledActionTemplate);
```

### Now we have the following issue:

We automatically build our apps with *jenkins* and some additional *bash scripts* which itself executes the resulting xcode build commands to create one resulting ipa. 
**But the created ipa does not log any event.** Even though the ipa is using the same *GoogleService-Info.plist* from working debug version within xcode.

So we added some debug logs to our app and also have a watch to the log from firebase:

Initialization seems ok:

```
standard    10:32:39.941315 +0200   hellfire    5.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.50000000 started
standard    10:32:39.941402 +0200   hellfire    5.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://xxxxxxxx)
```

While firebase initializes the right way it produces some error messages after logging an event:

```
standard    10:32:41.008690 +0200   hellfire    5.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012011] Received empty measurement bundle metadata for getting dictionary representation
standard    10:32:41.010648 +0200   hellfire    5.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023068] Data loss. Cannot record event metadata. Error: Error Domain=com.google.gmp.measurement.ErrorDomain Code=2 "Failed to insert/update unknown data type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to insert/update unknown data type}
standard    10:32:41.011612 +0200   hellfire    5.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS034010] Transaction failed
```

=> This error is the same with these firebase versions:

4.11.0 , 4.13.0 , 5.0.1

We spent now some days to check all build-settings, Firebase initialization (compare the docs) and we have no idea whats going wrong.
Assuming that all the Firebase projects are set up correctly, what else might we be missing?

Build-System currently uses this:

High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199) , 
Xcode 9.3 Build 9E145 , 
Cocoapods 1.5.0 , 
Firebase Core 5.0.1

Comment: I think there could be problem with the way you build. I have seen the problem occurred with NanoPB that Analytics uses, hence the error that you see.